# Modify android theme from appcompat theme

Tags: android, background, themes, android-appcompat, actionmode

Is there any way to change an attribute from the stock android themes, if the App is using the AppCompat theme?

**My Problem:**
I am using AppCompat theme in order to get the L-Look.
But I need to use the ActionMode, which is from basic Android API.
If I change the ActionMode style within my AppCompat theme, the style for the SupportedActionMode is applied.
But i defintily need the basic API ActionMode.

Does anybody know a way how to do this, in order to style my ActionMode background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *ActionMode* properties' names without `android:` prefix.