# Android Studio - Overflow Menu Theme

Tags: android, themes, overflow

I'm learning to make an Android overflow menu.

When I changed the theme of the app to show the 'Three Dots' of the overflow menu, Android Studio gave me an error:

[image: Error screenshot]

I realized that only the themes that begin with `AppCompat.something.something` are working properly. The rest are showing the error above. What is going wrong?

Comment: Check if your app supports the sdk version that the theme you want to use requires.  Also check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000948/modify-android-theme-from-appcompat-theme.

Comment: I am completely new to this. Can you tell me how to check that?

Comment: Check your .gradle files.  This link may also help: http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html.  Also, the theme you are talking about is called 'Material.'